# How to create link to directory in makefile in Linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, ln

I have makefile containing code below.

```
ddd :
    @mkdir -p /full/path_new/to/new_dir
    @ln -fs /full/path_old/to/old_dir/private /full/path_new/to/new_dir/private
```

Linux ln command creates link in both directory taget and parent. It means I have:

```
/full/path_new/to/new_dir:
private -> /full/path_old/to/old_dir/private
```

but also old one gets link

```
/full/path_old/to/old_dir/private
private -> /full/path_old/to/old_dir/private
```

It cause I have something like

```
/full/path_old/to/old_dir/private/private/private/private (...) endless
```

How should I use ln command to have link in new_dir only?

Comment: As an aside, putting `@` on everything you do is insane.  Run with `make -s` or specify `.SILENT: ddd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the existing link before you create it:

```
ddd :
        @mkdir -p /full/path_new/to/new_dir
        @rm -f /full/path_new/to/new_dir/private
        @ln -fs /full/path_old/to/old_dir/private /full/path_new/to/new_dir/private
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a clean slate, the proper way to do this would be to create a target which knows which dependency it is creating, and avoid creating it if it alread exists.

```
ddd: /full/path_new/to/new_dir/private
/full/path_new/to/new_dir/private:
    mkdir -p /full/path_new/to/new_dir
    ln -s /full/path/to/old_dir/private /full/path_new/to/new_dir
```

Comment: You should still delete first, or use `-f`.  If the symlink exists but points to an invalid directory then make will think it doesn't exist and run the `ln`, which will fail.

Comment: Although maybe it *should* fail in that case?

Comment: Possibly, of course, but I'm hard-pressed to imagine a scenario where failure would be preferred.